# How do I prove that $\{AB-BA\}$ does not span matrix space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field.

Let $W$ be the subspace of $M_n(F)$ generated by elements of the form $AB-BA$.

How do I prove that $dim(W)<n^2$?

Comment: Do you mean $W=\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}$ or $W=\langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle$?

Comment: @GitGud I meant the subspace not just that set, but if $W$ is the ideal generated by that, then is $W=M_n(F)$?

Comment: To me it's not even obvious that $\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}$ is a vector space. How do you prove that the sum is closed? Answering your question,$\langle X \rangle$ here denotes the smallest subspace containing $X$, so if $\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}$ is indeed a vector space, then $\langle \{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle=\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}$.

Comment: @GitGud I don't know that set is indeed a subspace or not. However, as I wrote in my post, I wrote $W$ to denote the **subspace** generated by that set. And even I think it's not going to be easy to prove or disprove that the set $\{AB-BA:A,B\in M_n(F)\}$ is indeed a subspace, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Again, to me it's not obvious how the answers help. Why should it be the case that all the matrices in $\langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle$ are of the form $AB-BA$?

Comment: Isn't it standard to say "the subspace of a vector space generated by a set $S$" to mean a subspace?...

Comment: I didn't say what I wanted to say in the first part of my previous comment. I have now removed it.

Comment: I understand what exactly you are talking about, but I'm afraid to say you misunderstood something. Of course i mean $\langle$ ~~~ $\rangle$, using your notation.

Comment: My question still stands.Now that it is clarified that you meant $W=\langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle$, I will ask the answerers.

Comment: @GitGud Any element of $W$ is of the form $\sum r_i AB-BA$, hence trace of every element of $W$ is $0$. I meant $F$-subspace of $M_m(F)$ not $M_m(F)$-submodule of $M_m(F)$.

Comment: Why is every element in $W$ of the form $\sum r_i AB-BA$?

Comment: @GitGud Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space and $S$ be a nonempty subset of $V$. Then it can be shown that $\{\sum_{i\in supp(f)} f(i)i : f\in F^S, \text {supp(f) is finite} \}$ is **the** subspace of $V$ generated by $S$.

Comment: Hang on, so we're talking about the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $F$, not the vector space? The question needs editing if this is the case.

Comment: @Chappers I meant the vector space, otherwise I would have tagged module or abstract algebra etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every element of $W$ has $0$ trace.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the trace.
$$ tr(AB-BA)= tr(AB)-tr(BA)=tr(AB)-tr(AB)=0 $$
Since (presumably) you are looking at linear combinations and products, you can't make the trace nonzero. There are elements with nonzero trace in $M_n$, which you can't get to.

Comment: Is it seems to me that you're assuming that every matrix in $\langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle$ is of the form $AB-BA$. Is this true?

Comment: @GitGud Since the trace is linear and we are looking at finite linear combinations, I don't see that there's anything that needs mentioning separately.

Comment: You want to prove that $\forall M\in \langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle(\text{tr}(M)=0)$, correct? To this effect you take an arbitrary $M\in \langle\{AB-BA\colon A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\}\rangle$, correct? Now what I get from your answer is that you assume without explanation that $M=AB-BA$ for some matrices $A,B$. And why this is the case, I have no idea.

Comment: It's a subspace spanned by elements of the form $AB-BA$, according to the OP. The trace is linear, so the trace and finite sums can be interchanged. Hence each element of the subspace is of the form $\sum_i \lambda_i C_i$, where $C_i$ is of the form $AB-BA$. Then $tr(\sum_i \lambda_i C_i) = \sum \lambda_i tr(C_i)$, and $tr(C_i) = 0$.

Comment: "Hence each element of the subspace is of the form (...)" How does that follow from what's before?

Comment: That's what a span is, a subspace of finite linear combinations?

Comment: I was missing that very basic fact, I completely forgot it. I kept thinking in terms of 'smallest subspace containing the set'. Thanks.